# Merging data between two dataframes for multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, vlookup

I've got two Excel Spreadsheets. The first has multiple columns, of which three (named differently) have common data. My second spreadsheet contains a key along with the data I want to bring into the first spreadsheet. For example:

Table 1:

| Target Company ID | Subsidiary ID | Parent Company ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

Table 2:

| Company ID | Company Size |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Small |
| 2 | Medium |
| 3 | Large |

With Excel I would do a series of Vlookups, but Table 1 is huge and is taking a long time to calculate. I would like to generate a Table such as:

| Target Company ID | Target Size | Subsidiary ID | Sub Size | Parent Company ID | Parent Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Small | 2 | Medium | 3 | Large |

I've tried `pd.merge`, but it is not as targeted as a `vlookup` would be in assign a value to the specific column

Answer (score 5):

You can make a mapping of `Company ID` to `Company Size` from `df2` by [`.set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and specify the column.

Then,
use [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map (*like looking up*) the `Company ID` in `df1` to the mapping for each column, as follows:

```
mapping = df2.drop_duplicates('Company ID').set_index('Company ID')['Company Size']

for col in df1.columns:
    df1[f'{col.split()[0]} Size'] = df1[col].map(mapping)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df1)

   Target Company ID  Subsidiary ID  Parent Company ID Target Size Subsidiary Size Parent Size
0                  1              2                  3       Small          Medium       Large
```

In case you have other columns in the dataframes, you can select the related columns by [`.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for all columns with column names end with `ID`, as follows:

```
mapping = df2.drop_duplicates('Company ID').set_index('Company ID')['Company Size']

# select column automatically by `.filter` or enter manually as a list
cols = df1.filter(regex=r'ID$').columns    

for col in cols:
    df1[f'{col.split()[0]} Size'] = df1[col].map(mapping)
```

In case you want to put the related columns together, you can further use [`.sort_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), as follows:

```
df1 = df1.sort_index(axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df1)

   Parent Company ID Parent Size  Subsidiary ID Subsidiary Size  Target Company ID Target Size
0                  3       Large              2          Medium                  1       Small
```

Comment: I get an error: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: try : `mapping = df2.drop_duplicates('Company ID').set_index('Company ID')['Company Size']`

Comment: @premiumcopypaper  Your table 2 has duplicated entries of Company ID ?  If yes, the code provided by Pascal can be used.

Comment: @PascalG.Bernard  Thanks for sharing the codes to handle the issue : -)

Comment: My pleasure @SeaBean - Congrats for the code you have provided -  I was working on it but you clearly outperformed my proposition

Comment: @premiumcopypaper  How's the codes works for you ?  Let me know your testing result. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, I also have duplicates in Table 1 as well, but I do not want to de-duplicate that table because I will need to do sums

Comment: @premiumcopypaper  The error should only be caused by Table 2.  Table 1 duplicates should have no problem with the codes above.  As we set index only on `Company ID`, with removing duplicates on `Company ID`  should be able to solve the error.  To solve the problem, we need to go deeply on the structure of your Table 2 in order to investigate the problem.  Would you please dump the first few lines of your Table 2 by eg. `df2.head(10).to_dict()` and put the result as an edit to your question ?

Comment: The error is being thrown in the function: `exposure_data[f'{col.split()[0]} Size'] = exposure_data[col].map(mapping)`

Comment: @premiumcopypaper  What's the error message you got for this line of code ?   Should be different from the previous one ?

Comment: @premiumcopypaper  Probably some special characteristic of your `exposure_data` that you didn't include in your sample data of Table 1 in the question.  Please dump the first few lines of it by `exposure_data.head(10).to_dict()` and put the result as an edit to your question.  Please also advise the error message you got.

Comment: I'm going to have to play around with your script; I can't get it to work and my data set is private; I did get my results need doing a series of merges though, but its not as elegant as your solution

Comment: @premiumcopypaper  Have you tested with just your sample data in the question and run my script in your environment ?   Want to isolate whether this is the data layout difference causing you can't use my script or whether it is programming environment difference.   If you can run based on your sample data, then probably some hidden problem in your data format incompatible with the solution.  Try and let me know the result.  Thanks!

Comment: @premiumcopypaper  How's play around with my codes ?  Is it fine ?  Got any hint of why your data being not compatible with the codes ?

Answer (score 0):

basic you want to marge the tables by left join 3 times each time tack a different column or just treat the 2 table as 3 tables like the following

```
table_1 = #read_file
table_2 = #read_file
targets = table_2[['Target Company ID','Target Size']]
Subsidiarys = table_2[['Subsidiary Company ID','Sub Size']]
Parents = table_2[['Parent Company ID','Parent Size']]
comb_table = pd.merge(table_1,targets,on=['Target Company ID'],how='left')
comb_table = pd.merge(comb_table ,Subsidiarys ,on=['Subsidiary Company ID'],how='left')
comb_table = pd.merge(comb_table ,Parents , on=['Parent Company ID'],how='left')
```